# Converting and downloading geospatial data

Tags: linux, excel, node.js, autocad, shapefile

I'm running NodeJS and MongoDB on a linux cloud server.

I need to give my users data in a variety of formats:

- Shapefile (shp)
- Autocad (dxf)
- Excel
  (xls/xlsx)

It would also be nice to be able to generate Word (.docx/.doc) files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found a python library for generating shp files so I'll probably use that http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/ Now I need to figure out autocad and excel files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an AutoCAD API, http://www.opendesign.com/ is the cheapest way. There may be other DXF libraries out there but I doubt they are as refined as the ODA or the official AutoCAD SDK.

Search the AutoCAD tag for more Q&As on DWG & DXF SDKs.